# DFPT vs analytical nuclear gradient

Tags: molecular-dynamics, phonons, intermolecular-forces, dfpt

I have read some literatures about the gradient wrt. atom positions of the DFT energy, and find different methods one commonly used in MD(analytical nuclear gradient,[pulay's paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-8541-7_4)), and another usually used in phonon calculations(DFPT,[the introduction in QE](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/ph_user_guide.pdf) and [a brief introduction](https://zeilazanolli.files.wordpress.com/2019/04/2013_dfpt_c2_verstraete_zanolli.pdf)).

Since they compute the same physical targets, why we make different choice in different tasks? Or what's the main difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not the same quantity. The gradient of the energy with respect to the position $\vec{R}_i=(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ of atom $i$ gives the *force*, $\vec{F}_i$, acting on that atom,
$$
\vec{F}_i=-\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial E}{\partial y_i},\frac{\partial E}{\partial z_i}\right).
$$
One important thing to note is that the changes in the electronic (Kohn-Sham) density when the atoms move do not contribute to the forces.

Since we usually want the forces on *all* the atoms, it is convenient to redefine the indices of the position and force vectors to run over all $3N$ components of the atomic positions; e.g. for $N$ atoms we have an "all atom" position vector
$$
\vec{R}=\left(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2,~\ldots~,x_N,y_N,z_N\right).
$$
This allows us to write the "all atom" force vector compactly as,
$$
\vec{F}_i=-\frac{\partial E}{\partial R_i}.
$$

In contrast to the forces, the phonons depend on the force-constant matrix, which is essentially the *curvature* of the energy, $\mathrm{K}$
$$
\mathrm{K}_{ij}= \frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial R_i \partial R_j},
$$
remembering that these are "all atom" indices, so there are $3N$ values of $i$ and $j$ for $N$ atoms.

As well as requiring the first-order change in the Kohn-Sham states, the curvature of the energy is sensitive to the first-order changes in the electronic density when the atoms move, so $\mathrm{K}$ has to be computed self-consistently.